# How to project a polygon on an axis

Tags: java, math, geometry, polygons

I'm trying to learn the **Separating Axis Theorem**. This is because I'm making a simple 2D game and I need this as a way to detect if two polygons are intersecting.

Problem is, I suck at math.

So far, I understand that in order to know if two polygon are intersecting, I need to do the following:

1. Creata a perpendicular line to every edge of the two polygons.
2. Project each polygon to each of the new lines created (the axes).

If **all** projections of the first polygon overlap **all** projections of the second polygon, the shapes intersect. Else, the shapes do not intersect.

I think I understand how to do step 1. But I don't understand how to perform step two.

How can I project a polygon onto an axis? Please explain this in a language I will be able to understand, as a person with pretty basic knowledge at math.

(Although I *did* learn some math concepts such as dot product and vectors, at a basic level. So you *can* talk to me using these terms.)

Theoretical explanation will be great, but an example on how to implement this in code (preferably Java), will also be welcome.

Help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: This is a useful tutorial: http://www.codezealot.org/archives/55

Comment: [Point in polygon](http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/~wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html) algorithm will probably get you what you need.  All you need to know is if one of the vertices is in the other polygon really. Well... unless one intersects only a line.

Comment: @gtgaxiola I am learning through this tutorial. But I got stuck at the point that explains how to project a polygon onto an axis. That's what's written in the tutorial: _"To project a polygon onto an axis is relatively simple; loop over all the vertices, performing the dot product with the axis and storing the minimum and maximum."_
I don't understand this. _what_ minimum and maximum?

Comment: If there's no case when one polygon is entirely contained in the other, you can probably just check if any lines from 1 polygon, intersect with any lines from the other

Comment: @Felix Castor Not so. Conside the triangle with vertices (10, 0) (10, 10), (11, 0) and the triangle with vertices (12, 5), (12, 6), (3, 6). They intersect but no corner is in the other triangle.

Comment: Say I only need to detect collision between rectangle-shaped Polygons. So in this case, point in polygon algorithm will always work, right?

Comment: Daniel Martin has a good point.  If you only considered the vertices of both then no, there is a case where one rectangles vertices aren't in the other's but they do intersect.  But you could walk along the perimeter of one and check if the points of that perimeter are inside the other's using the point in poly.

Comment: You're saying that there could be a situation where one rectangle doesn't have vertices in the other, but they do intersect. But could there be a situation, where *both* rectangles don't have vertices in each other, and they intersect?

Answer (score 4):

Look at scalar multiplication of two vectors:

```
(A ⋅ B) = |A| ⋅ |B| ⋅ cos(a);
```

- `A, B` are vectors.
- `a` is angle between `A, B`.

So if you want size of `A` projected onto `B = C`:

```
|C| = |A| ⋅ cos(a);
|C| = (A ⋅ B) / |B|;
```

If you do not know the formulas or You are not sure of symbols then:

```
|B| = sqrt((B.x)² + (B.y)² + (B.z)² + ...);
A ⋅ B = (A.x ⋅ B.x) + (A.y ⋅ B.y) + (A.z ⋅ B.z) + ...;
```

[image: scalar multiplication]

So now just take all the lines and project them as vectors like this:

[image: line projection]

```
x0 = ((L0 - A0) ⋅ (A1 - A0)) / |(A1 - A0)|;
x1 = x0 + ((L1 - L0) ⋅ (A1 - A0)) / |(A1 - A0)|;
```

**[Notes]**

If you set axis vector `(A1 - A0)` as unit ... `|A| = 1` then you can forget about the therm `/ |(A1 - A0)|` which speeds things up a lot.